# how to restrict with 6 images and how to display the uploaded images

Tags: html, vue.js

I am trying to display the images instead of image name. So here I am displaying image name and I also want to display the images which is uploaded. And also I we can restrict the user to upload only a six image. So below is my code please if any one have an idea help me. So here in my code user able to upload many images but i want to restrict with only six images.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="asad">
<template >
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h2>Multiple Files</h2>
            <hr/>
            <label>Files
                <input type="file" multiple @change="handleFileUploads( $event )"/>
                <ul v-if="files.length">
                <li v-for="(name, i) in filesNames" :key="i">{{ name }}</li>
                <li>{{ files }}</li>
                </ul>
            </label>
            
            <div>
                <img v-for="image in images" :src="image" />
              </div>
            
            <br>
            <button v-on:click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
</body>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#asad',
  data(){
    return {
      files: [],
      images: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filesNames() {
      const fn = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        fn.push(this.files.item(i).name)
      }
      return fn
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    handleFileUploads( event ){
      this.files = event.target.files;
    },

    submitFile(){
      let formData = new FormData();
      for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
        let file = this.files[i];
        formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
        this.images.push(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      }

      axios.post( '/multiple-files', formData, 
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}
      ).then(function(){
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
      })
      .catch(function(){
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
      });
    }
  }
})
  
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type down this for limiting the upload images. In this example I have limited upto 3 images. You could modify the code to limit 6 images

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML file upload</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <input type="file"  action="/action_page.php"  name="name" multiple><br/>
         Upload multiple files, and click Submit.<br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
      </form>
      <script>
         $(function(){
            $("input[type = 'submit']").click(function(){
               var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
               if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 3){
                  alert("You are only allowed to upload a maximum of 3 files");
               }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya jain. Here how can we display the uploaded images

Comment: To display uploaded Images in JavaScript just add the following code...

<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
<p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></p>
<p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>

<script>
var loadFile = function(event) {
 var image = document.getElementById('output');
 image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
</script>